# Heatmap with different sized rectangles and colors

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, heatmap

There are several heatmap implementations for R. All of them have in common that they span (dimension 1 and 2) a matrix with equal sized rectangles. The color of the rectangle then shows the height of a measure (dimension 3).

The kind of heatmap I am looking for is a bit different. For every entry (Dimension 1) I would like to have a rectangle. The rectangle's size should represent the value of dimension 2 and its color dimension 3.

Do these kind of heatmaps have a special name? And is there a R implementation?

When googling I can find images like these (not created in R):
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of visualization is called a [treemap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping). There seem to be several R packages for creating them

Comment: Thank you. Searching the same and your name suggestion helps a lot.